# executing code from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code stored in the database, I need to execute it when retrieved.

But my code is a mix of HTML and PHP, mainly used in echo "";

A sample that looks like my code:

```
echo "Some Text " . $var['something'] . " more text " . $anotherVar['something2'];
```

How can I execute a code like the either if I add the data to the DB with `echo"";` or without it.

Any ideas?

***UPDATE:***

I forgot to mention, I'm using this on a website that will be used on intranet and security will be enforced on the server to ensure data safety.

Comment: Storing HTML or PHP code in a DB is usually a bad idea.  Is the PHP code just string concatenation?  You could probably use a regex to replace the variable names with their values.

Comment: Wow, how did you end up in having php that needs to be executed stored in a database? Sounds like a major design flaw.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Yeah, I guess.  HTML can be in the DB, that's fine.

Comment: I would _seriously_ consider your approach if you are having to store PHP code in your database. This is a pretty big security flaw. HTML is fine and quite common, but I wouldn't recommend executing any server-side code from data that comes from your database.

Comment: @ALL: I'm totally aware of the risk, but I intent to use the website on intranet.

Comment: @sikas the problem is not really about security. That's only one of the problems, but not the main one by far.

Answer (score 18):

> I have a PHP code stored in the database

STOP now.
Move the code out of the database.
And never mix your *code* with *data* again.

Answer (score 3):

It's not only a bad idea but also invitation to several type of **hacking attempts**.

You can do with `eval()`. but never use it . The `eval()` is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

See [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). It lets you pass a string containing PHP and run it as if you'd written it directly into your file.

It's not a common practice to store executable PHP in a database; is the code you store really that different that it makes more sense to maintain many copies of it rather than adapting it to do the same thing to static data in the database? The use of `eval` is often considered bad practice as it can lead to problems with maintenance, if there's a way of avoiding it, it's normally worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute code with eval():

```
$code_str = "echo 'Im executed'";
eval($code_str );
```

BUT PAY ATTENTION that this is not safe: if someone will get access on your database he will be able to execute any code on your server

Answer (score 1):

use the eval() function.

heres some info

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

something along the lines of:

```
eval($yourcode);
```

If that is the last resort, you want it to be secure as it will evaluate anything and hackers love that.  Look into Suhosin or other paths to secure this in production.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone'd indicated using eval() is a bad approach for your need. But you can have almost the same result by using whitelist approach.

- Make a php file , db_driven_functions.php for instance. get your data from db. and map them in an array as below

> //$sql_fn_parameters[0] = function name
>
> //$sql_fn_parameters[1,2,3.....] = function parameters

- Then define functions those include your php code blocks.for instance

  > ```
  > my_echo($sql_fn_parameters){
  >
  >      echo $sql_fn_parameters[1];//numbered or assoc..
  >
  > }
  > ```
- then pull the data which contains function name
- after controlling if that function is defined

> ```
> function_exists("$sql_fn_parameters[0]")
> ```

- call function

> call_user_func_array() or call_user_func()
>   
>   ( any you may also filter parameters array $sql_sourced_parameters_array does not contain any risky syntaxes for more security.)

And have your code controlled from db without a risk.

seems a little bit long way but after implementing it's really a joy to use an admin panel driven php flow.

BUT building a structure like this with OOP is better in long term. (Autoloading of classes etc. )

Comment: for function parameters to be stored in db you can also use serialize() and unserialize() to make this standartdized

Answer (score 0):

Eval is not safe obviously.

The best route IMO

1. Save your data in a table
2. Run a stored procedure when you are ready to grab and process that data

Answer (score 0):

You should not abuse the database this way. And in general, dynamic code execution is a bad idea. You could employ a more elegant solution to this problem using template engines like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/crash_course) or [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few way to achieve this:

**1) By using evil**

`eval($data);`

That's not a typo, eval is usually considered evil and for good reasons. If you think you have fully validated user data to safely use `eval`, you are likely wrong, and have given a hacker full access to your system. Even if you only use `eval` for your own data, hacking the database is now enough to gain full access to everything else. It's also a nightmare to debug code used in `eval`.

**2) Save the data to a file, then include it**

`file_put_contents($path, $data); include $path;`

There are still the same security concerns as `eval` but at least this time the code is easier to debug. You can even test the code before executing it, eg:

```
if (strpos(exec('php -l '.$path), 'No syntax errors detected') === false))
{
    include $path;
}
```

The downside to this method, is the extra overhead involved in saving the code.

**3) Execute the code straight from the database.**

You'd need to use database software that allows this. As far as I am aware, this is only includes database software that stores the content as text files. Having database software with "php eval" built in would not be a good thing. You could try [txt-db-api](https://github.com/deian/zoobar/blob/master/txt-db-api/txt-db-api.php). Alternatively, you could write your own. It would like become very difficult to maintain if you do though but is something to consider if you know exactly how you want your data to be structured and are unlikely to change your mind later.

This could save a lot of overhead and have many speed benefits. It likely won't though. Many types of queries run way faster using a traditional database because they are specifically designed for that purpose. If there's a possibility of trying to write to a file more than once at the same time, then you have to create a locking method to handle that.

**4) Store php code as text files outside of the database**

If your database contains a lot of data that isn't php code, why even store the php code in the database? This could save a lot of overhead, and if you're database is hacked, then it may no longer be enough to gain full access to your system.

**Some of the security considerations**

Probably more than 99% of the time, you shouldn't even be attempting to do what you are doing. Maybe you have found an exception though, but just being an intranet, isn't enough, and certainly doesn't mean it's safe to ignore security practices. Unless everyone on the intranet needs full admin access, they shouldn't be able to get it. It's best for everyone to have the minimum privileges necessary. If one machine does get hacked, you don't want the hacker to have easy access to everything on the entire intranet. It's likely the hacker will hide what they are doing and will introduce exploits to later bypass your server security.

I certainly need to do this for the CMS I am developing. I'm designing it mainly to produce dynamic content, not static content. The data itself is mostly code. I started off with simple text files, however it slowly evolved into a complicated text file database. It's very fast and efficient, as the only queries I need are very simply and use indexing. I am now focusing on hiding the complexity from myself and making it easy to maintain with greater automation. Directly writing php code or performing admin tasks requires a separate environment with Superuser access for only myself. This is only out of necessity though, as I manage my server from within, and I have produced my own debugging tools and made an environment for code structured a specific way that hides complexity. Using a traditional code editor, then uploading via ssh would now be too complicated to be efficient. Clients will only be able to write php code indirectly though and I have to go to extreme lengths to make that possible, just to avoid the obvious security risks. There are not so obvious ones too. I've had to create an entire framework called `Jhp` and every piece of code, is then parsed into `php`. Every function has to pass a whitelist, is renamed or throws an error, and every variable is renamed, and more. Without writing my own parser and with just a simple blacklist, it would never be even a tiny bit secure. Nothing whatsoever client-side can be trusted, unless I can confirm on every request that it has come entirely from myself, and even then my code error checks before saving so I don't accidentally break my system, and just in case I still do, I have  another identical environment to fix it with, and detailed error information in the console that even works for fatal errors, whilst always been hidden from the public.

**Conclusion**

Unless you go to the same lengths I have (at minimum), then you will probably just get hacked. If you are sure that it is worth going to those lengths, then maybe you have found an exception. If your aim is to produce code with code, then the data is always going to be code and it cannot be separated. Just remember, there are a lot more security considerations other than what I have put in this answer and unless the entire purpose of what you are doing makes this a necessity, then why bother at all mix data with code?